# How to retain transformed data-frame loaded in pyspark if source data is deleted during execution after data load?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am doing below steps , and in the process I am losing the transformed data though I am using cache() on the data .

**STEP -1 : READ DATA FROM CASSANDRA:**

```
data = spark_session.read \
            .format('org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra') \
            .options(table=table, keyspace=keyspace) \
            .load()
data_cached = data.cache()
```

**STEP-2: READ DATA FROM AWS S3 BUCKET LET'S SAY S3_data_path**

```
s3_full_df = spark.read.format("parquet").load(S3_data_path)
full_data  = s3_full_df .cache() 
full_data.show(n=1, truncate=False)
```

**STEP-3: Finding difference between cassandra data from step-1 and s3 parquet file data from step -2**

```
diff_data = data_cached.subtract(full_data)
diff_data_cached = diff_data .cache()
diff_data_cached.count()
```

**STEP-4: writing step-3 data diff_data_cached  into aws s3 bucket , let's say s3_diff_path**

```
diff_data_cached.write.parquet(inc_path)
```

**STEP-5: IMP STEP : overwriting cassandra data from step -1 to aws s3 path S3_data_path ( in STEP-2)**

```
data_cached.write.parquet(full_path, mode="overwrite")
```

**STEP -6 : writing diff_data_cached  in database . This step has issue .**

diff_data_cached  is available in STEP-3 is written to data base but after STEP-5 diff_data_cached  is empty , My assumption is as in STEP-5 , data is overwritten with STEP-1 data and hence there is no difference between two data-frames, but since I have run cache() operation on diff_data_cached   and then have run count() to load data in memory so my expectation is diff_data_cached   should be available in memory for STEP-6 , rather than spark lazily evaluates.

Comment: title is odd, you mean retain the cache?

Comment: yes , I want to retain cache() but I am losing cached data , if my origin data is no longer available .

Answer (score 0):

You are 1) writing in the Hadoop / Big Data domain *back to a source* that 2) has had *caching applied* and are 3) therefore *invalidating* the cache.

In the past I am pretty sure this did not happen - the invalidation that is as the(underlying) immutable RDD was considered to be a snapshot of a data source.
I base this on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24596.

I do wonder if you filtered on partitions that are no longer being written to, then a write to a new partition if that has the same effect. I will be checking that soon and will post you.

Answer (score 0):

This particular issue was happening during write into s3 bucket , and due to spark lazy evaluation truncate was happening before reading already existing data .
here is my solution to the problem:

1. cache() on data-frame
2. action on data-frame . for example show(n=1, truncate=False) This will help loading data-frame into memory .